# SUMPRODUCT formula is only counting some dates within specified ranges

Tags: excel, date, integer, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have an Excel formula to count the number of times a date shows in a specific period:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Reg. 2013'!B:B>=D10)*('Reg. 2013'!B:B<=E10))
```

The problem is that this formula is only counting some dates. I've checked the formatting and auto calculation and it shows incorrect values.

For ex: between 24/08/2013  30/08/2013 it shows `8` but they are 12,
and between 31/08/2013  31/08/2013 it shows `0` but there are 2.

Why might this be?

[image: SO27532981 question example]

Comment: I'm not sure that this question shouldn't be on [su], but ignoring that there's not enough information here to answer, and I'm not visiting some link (even if it did work) to download some potentially malicious file.

Comment: @pnuts, yes, you are correct - you could solve it by changing to this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(('Reg. 2013'!B:B>=D10)*('Reg. 2013'!B:B<E10+1))` - I changed `<=E10` at the end to `<E10+1`

Comment: @pnuts something like:  =SUMPRODUCT((INT('Reg. 2013'!B:B)>=D10)*(INT('Reg. 2013'!B:B)<=E10))

Comment: @pnuts Yes, Barry's works.  And INT does return an array of values.  The only issue with using INT is that, if the column has a text header, it will return a #VALUE! error; so one would either have to add logic to deal with that, or exclude the column header from the range to be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys, it worked with ron sugestion
=SUMPRODUCT((INT('Reg. 2013'!B:B)>=D10)*(INT('Reg. 2013'!B:B)<=E10))
thanks